# How can I visualize the folders and files as a tree on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-management, visualization, tree-view

How can I visualize all sub folders and files of an self-defined root folder on Windows?

The result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with File Explorer, `Windows-E`?

Comment: It shows only folders or files not both in a tree as far as i know.

Answer (score 2):

just type TREE at the command prompt, 
you can direct the output to a file if you want TREE> directory.txt

Comment: Ok but it does not contain icons for .jpg .txt etc. I want to use it for a documentation.

Comment: Please try > TREE /F. Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree